# BASH script file - run command with alias in interactive mode -> prevent logout/exit

Tags: bash, command, exit, interactive

I am trying to run Variable as command with aliases sourced from file

Bash script file:

```
source /...path_to_file.../file.txt
#. /...path_to_file.../file.txt

CMD="$...variable1..."' '"$...variable2..."

bash -c -i "$CMD" 2>&1 &    ...this works ok, as expected.
```

Afterwards when I press any key, Logout and Exit pop-ups in terminal line and terminal close itself.

I had tried:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases ...didnt help

set -o ignoreeof ...didnt help
```

How can I run Bash script file with Bash command including expanded alias in interactive mode (shell) and prevent Terminal (NOT to) logout and exit?

Comment: You need to export the aliases to have the shell run by `bash -c` inherit them.

Comment: How can I.......to export aliases in Bash script file? Since they are sourced from other file....